# Annuity present value formula explanation

Tags: fractions, finance

Could somene please explain me how the formula evolves, ie. how does the fraction flip, etc? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: If one knows about these things, it is not hard to describe in words the annuity whose PV is given by the formula. However, for completeness that annuity should be described precisely. Presumably $C$ is the amount we get each year (or month), and $r$ is the yearly (or monthly) interest rate, compounded yearly (monthly). And $t$ is the number of payments, with the first payment coming now.

Comment: It looks like there is a typo here, it goes from $C/[\frac{\dots}{r}]$ to $C\cdot [\frac{\dots}{r}]$

Comment: it is as you said Andre Nicolas. I understand the annuity. I dont understand how the formula transforms to c x ((1/r )-(1/r(1+r)^t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are asking?

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{1 - [1/(1+r)^t]}{r} &= \frac{1 - \frac{1}{(1+r)^t}}{r} \\
&= \frac{1}{r} \bigg( 1- \frac{1}{(1+r)^t}\bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{r} -  \frac{1}{r(1+r)^t}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, but how do you get r in front of parantheses? r(1+r)t

Comment: I just distribute that $\frac{1}{r}$. @proximus

Comment: Yes, almost. How do you make C from numerator to multiplicator

Comment: That's the same confusion pointed out by another user in the comment. In my answer I only deal with the last equality. Not sure how to go from the second to the third.